# Regex MySQL Insert

Tags: mysql, regex, text

I got these Text Lines from an MySQL Insert and want to add an ).

```
(2, 1, 1, '', 'xxxx', FROM_BASE64('/9j/4...kf/Z', 'xxx', 0, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', '', 'xxxx', '', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0, '', '0', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'),
```

I need to add an ) to every FROM_BASE64('')

So this

```
(2, 1, 1, '', 'xxxx', FROM_BASE64('/9j/4...kf/Z', 'xxx', 0, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', '', 'xxxx', '', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0, '', '0', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'),
```

Becomes this

```
(2, 1, 1, '', 'xxxx', FROM_BASE64('/9j/4...kf/Z'), 'xxx', 0, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', '', 'xxxx', '', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0, '', '0', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'),
```

The ) after the Base64 String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 encodings cannot contain a single quote, so this should be rather easy:

```
s/FROM_BASE64('[^']*'/&)/
```

Explanation:

- `'[^']*'`: match a single quote followed by 0 or more non-single-quote characters, followed by another single quote
- `&`: the complete match

You can [try it out online](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1jfLcjfN97JMdjVzERDPTpOPVZLXV9NU///fw0jHQVDMFJXB@IKIADSKMr1LbP0TfT09LLT9KOgaoCUAZyFnUIyTV2dgFpslAFUnwHpmjV1AA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works flawless